# Clasificación de variables

Tags: sql

Tengo una tabla donde me aparece la sesión de los cliente, el cliente, la página web donde ha entrado, la acción que ha hecho y la fecha con la hora. Me han pedido hacer un funnel para ver los movimientos de los clientes en nuestra pagina web, teniendo en cuenta que un cliente ha podido entrar en la home, ha elegido un producto, ha ido al market y ha hecho la compra, mientras que otro cliente ha ido a la home ha cogido un producto lo ha enviado al carrito y ha vuelto a la home ha mirado otro producto lo ha cogido y ha ido finalmente al carrito a pagarlo. Así sería una representación de cómo sería la tabla:

[image: tabla]

El funnel que me han pedido sería un funnel donde empiece en Home y ver cuántos de estos clientes han llegado al market final haciendo la compra finalmente, viendo los pasos intermedios o donde han hecho click antes, y esto había pensado hacerlo por one hot encoding con la columna de link, pero mi duda es qué hacer con los que vuelve a home en la misma sesión. Un posible funnel sería algo así:

[image: graficas]

Había pensado en una tabla parecida a esta:

> cliente// Date // Home // Product // Market //

¿Me podéis ayudar a clasificarlo de una manera que la tabla que me devuelva sea clara para hacer el funnel?

De manera básica estoy utilizando este código:

```
SELECT Sesion, Cliente, date (datetime) as Fecha, 
       count (case when  page = 'www.home.com'      THEN '1' end) as Home,
       count (case when page LIKE '%product_id%'                                                 
        THEN '1' end) as Producto,
        count (case when page = 'www.market.com'        THEN '1' end) as 
        Carrito
FROM d_navigation
where datetime > '2023-01-01' 
group by date (datetime)
order by date (datetime) desc
```

Saludos

Comment: En preguntas de SQL es buena idea incluir, en etiquetas, información del motor que usas. Sobre todo en estas, que van un poco más allá de un query básico y probablemente salen mejor si tiran de las características específicas del motor y también si excluyen las que no soporta el motor de marras.

Por otro lado, hay varios temas: en tu tabla de ejemplo se ve el caso del cliente ab777 que hizo tres sesiones distintas, la última directamente al market. ¿cómo quieres procesar eso?

Comment: También, yo con sombrero de gente de marketing o de ventas, no veo mayor diferencia si en una sesión el cliente fue y vino 17 veces del home y la página de productos, para finalmente ir al market y pagar... en el _funnel_ para mi eso sería una única conversión. En tu requerimiento, ¿cuántas conversiones son?

Comment: Finalmente, escribir toda esta consulta sin ver esfuerzo de tu parte puede dejar una sensación de estar haciendo tu trabajo. Sugiero que aportes las consultas que has intentado o, al menos, la base, con datos no en una imagen, sino como texto, o un fiddle con los datos cargados y, debo insistir, una consulta de punto de partida de la cual tirar para ayudarte con la parte que no logras hacer, pero no hacer tu trabajo completo.

Comment: Hola @jachguate, lo siento, no quiero que hagáis mi trabajo ni mucho menos, sino que me ayudéis a dar una pincelada de cómo poder pintar este flujo que hacen mis clientes. Gracias, Saludos,

Comment: Sin embargo, no respondes a mis preguntas ni añades la etiqueta que te he pedido. :(